# Wrong frame rate and metadata when saving RTSP stream to file

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I use VLC to save a RTSP stream from IP camera to mp4 file. In Convert/Save dialog, I choose

```
+ Encapsulation: MP4/MOV
+ Video codec: Keep original video track (not using transcode)
```

VLC has saved file successfully, but the file has some wrong metadata. File size ~ 25GB (about 12 hours), but duration in metadata is 7 minutes 25 seconds.

```
Stream 0:
Codec: H264- MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Video resolution: 1920x1080
Frame rate: 2701.222144
```

When I seek to 7:25 (end of progress bar), the video doesn't stop, vlc still continues playing.

I also try using vlc command line but saved file still has wrong metadata.

```
cvlc --rtsp-http RTSP_URL --sout "#std{access=file,dst=vlc.mp4,mux=mp4}" vlc://quit
```

I think that VLC got problem with timestamp with RTSP stream. Could anyone give me some idea about this problem ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

- Save stream into many small files (Ex: 60 minutes per each file)
- Use tool untrunc to fix corrupted file